# STDIN prevents activating of other file descriptors

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, stdin, posix-select

The following program is written to receive clients' messages and read user inputs from keyboard:

```
FD_ZERO(&masterfds);
FD_SET(udp_con, &masterfds);
FD_SET(0, &masterfds);
maxfds = udp_con;
while(exit == false)
{ 
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  readfds = masterfds;

  selectFunc = select(maxfds+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  if(selectFunc < 0) {
    message("error in select");
    exit = true;
  } else {
    // The server has received something from a client
    for(i = 0; i <= maxfds; i++) {
      if(FD_ISSET(i, &readfds)) {
        if(FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
          fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
          int len = strlen(userInput) - 1;
          if (userInput[len] == '\n') {
            userInput[len] = '\0';
          }
          cout<<"The user said: "<<userInput<<endl;
        } else if(i == udp_con) {
          cout<<"Datagram received"<<endl;
          // After reading the user input, it never reaches here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the 'enter' key on the keyboard and the '0' file descriptor activates, the program will never activate any other file descriptor and it locks on the '0' file descriptor. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: `if(FD_ISSET(0, &readfds))` -> `if (i == 0)`.

Comment: @n.m.: Or just take the `i == 0` case outside the loop.  In fact, why is there a loop anyway?

Comment: @BenVoigt I think the for loop should only work when we have TCP connections and we add more file descriptors to the master file descriptor set. Is that correct?

Comment: @Amir: Then there would be some advantage to having *a* loop.  Still no reason to loop through all file descriptors.  If you have a table of TCP sockets, loop through that table.

Comment: Related: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to `FD_CLR(0, readfds)` after you test it with `FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)`, or else it will *always* take that branch.

But you can simplify the algorithm by rewriting it. It's a good idea to get into the habit of formatting your code to make it easily readable.

```
FD_ZERO(&masterfds);
FD_SET(udp_con, &masterfds);
FD_SET(0, &masterfds);
maxfds = udp_con;

while (true) {
  readfds = masterfds;

  selectFunc = select(maxfds + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
  if (selectFunc < 0) {
    message("error in select");
    break;
  }

  // Check for input on stdin (fd 0).
  if (FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
    fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin);
    int len = strlen(userInput) - 1;
    if (userInput[len] == '\n') {
      userInput[len] = '\0';
    }
    cout << "The user said: '" << userInput << "'" << endl;
  }
  // Check for input on the udp_con fd.
  if (FD_ISSET(udp_con, &readfds)) {
    cout << "Datagram received" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: When I FD_CLR(0, &readfds) since I will replace the readfds contents with masterfds, 0 will get back to the readfds for the next iteration. Also, the program must be able to read both the user inputs and datagrams constantly. How should I do this?
The (i == 0) doesn't work also.

Comment: You need the bit to be clear while inside your `for()` loop. It's fine that it gets reset atop the `while()`. The code I wrote _does_ read both user input and the UDP descriptor constantly, inside a `while (true)` loop, and eliminates the unnecessary nested `for()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see where you have used the FD_CLR() function in your code. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: I don't need `FD_CLR()` because I eliminated the `for()` loop. I test specifically for fd 0 and the udp_con descriptor, then `readfds` is reset to `masterfds` at the top of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me!!!
I'm running the program on Linux. Does it make sense?